# Require php files in the server does not work

Tags: php

In my efforts within Hostinger, I'm working on getting a PHP website published. The testing phase with a basic "index.php" file featuring a simple "coming soon" page went smoothly. Strangely, though, once I uploaded the entire website, it stopped functioning as expected. The core "index.php" file of the site includes PHP code that links to a template page housing the HTML content, achieved through the line: `require('public-templates/t_index.php');`

Upon directing to myDomain.com, a blank white page greets me. Investigation using the browser's developer tools uncovers an absence of content.  I don’t know actually if the problem is with the file requiring or not.

Despite making contact with Hostinger's customer service, their attempts to assist haven't resolved the issue. Might you be able to offer some guidance in addressing this situation?
As a troubleshooting step, I've enabled error logs, but strangely, no error messages are appearing.

Comment: Do you actually have a directory called `public-templates` that contains a file called `t_index.php`?

Comment: Yes I have. I even tried to take it out of the folder and to change the path in the require line but nothing changed

Comment: "*a blank white page greets me*" - Please enable [error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) and provide us with the correct error(s)

Answer (score -1):

1. So you're doing myDomain.com to visit your site, sometimes what
   happens is while uploading it uploads as foldername and inside
   files,    so maybe try myDomain.com/foldername/index.php
2. if your index.php file is directly inside Public_html then I would    advice to check the permissions such as if it is in 775 or755.
3. Also make sure you are giving correct database details in your config file  with respect to the Hostinger database.

Comment: Actually, I tried those there points and nothing changed.

Comment: Try to host in another hosting provider for testing, "infinityfree" is a free hosting provider for php, if your site loads successfully there, then it must be issue with Hositnger. (Note this is not a Promotion, i have no association with infinityfree, i only use it to test sites there)